# POST and Patch is not working in POSTMAN with JSON data

Tags: node.js, json, post, postman, patch

I am use NodeJS and mongodb for database and mongoose

[I am provided value for name and email but it still shows that email and name required]

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHO0B.png)

Here is my code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const validator = require('validator')

const User = mongoose.model('User', {

name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    tolowercase: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true,
    validate(value){
        if(!validator.isEmail(value)){
            throw new Error('Invalid Email')
        }
    }
},

password: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 7,
    //required: true,
    trim: true,
    validate(value){
        if(value.toLowerCase().includes('password')){
            throw new Error('Password can\'t contains word password')
        }
    }
},

age: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
}
})
```

If I comment all required statement in name and email then also it will take only age and save it into db

Comment: How are you storing/saving the incoming data from the request. Please update that part of the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's most probably happening because of the Mismatching of Content-Type, what you are sending from the postman and what you are receiving in your node app.
Please check if you are using body-parser and parsing the data in JSON 
like:
  app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
and not like:
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
As I think you must be sending a header with Content-Type: application/json from the postman and receiving it as urlencoded or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

The "path" part in the error response could indicate that the parameter belongs in the URL path not the body.